# Attempting tom make a phenakistoscope with framerjs utilities

Tags: framerjs

[This](http://share.framerjs.com/ifv66i5c9emt/) is a as far as I got. Im trying to make a [Phenaniskope](http://codepen.io/fixcl/pen/swkgA)

```
bg = new BackgroundLayer
    backgroundColor: "pink"

frame = new Layer
    width: 250
    height: 250
    image: "images/phenakistoscope.png"

frame.center()

Utils.interval 1, ->
    cycler = Utils.cycle([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
    frame.rotation = cycler()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some quick changes and explained in the comments:

http://share.framerjs.com/kr6mvm4y8xcl/

Basically, you left the cycler inside the interval, so it was being "reset" every time, thus you would stop at rotation 10.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great job solving the OP's problem; you should include the new code in your answer for future readers in case the link you provided becomes broken.

Comment: You area legend of code. Thanks so much for your time